# How to get the lastest node.js release on Joyent's no.de service

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a node app and looking to deploy on Joyent, which I'm pretty new to.

I ran `node -v` on my server at no.de and got `v0.4.11`

The same command run locally gives `v0.5.11-pre`.

What are the options for getting the latest node release on joyent's service?

Comment: Have you tried just installing it or (if you can't install it) emailing joyent and asking them to install 0.5.10? (P.S. running `x-pre` is risky, I recommend the non-pre versions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out on my own.

The answer (you guessed it) is [buried in the joyent docs](http://wiki.joyent.com/display/node/Getting+Started+with+a+Node.js+SmartMachine) on setting up an instance.

Basically you create a file named `config.json` and add it to the base of your project. In that file you add a parameter indicating which version or node you want. Mine looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "v0.5" 
}
```

This makes sure I get the latest supported version of 0.5, which as I write this is 0.5.3

Here's a list of those versions currently supported:

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 24561 staff    6 2011-08-23 22:41 v0.4.10
drwxr-xr-x 6 24561 staff    6 2011-08-23 22:41 v0.4.11
drwxr-xr-x 6 24561 staff    6 2011-08-23 22:41 v0.4.6
drwxr-xr-x 6 24561 staff    6 2011-08-23 22:41 v0.4.7
drwxr-xr-x 6 24561 staff    6 2011-08-23 22:41 v0.4.8
drwxr-xr-x 6 24561 staff    6 2011-08-23 22:41 v0.4.9
drwxr-xr-x 6 24561 staff    6 2011-08-23 22:41 v0.5.0
drwxr-xr-x 6 24561 staff    6 2011-08-23 22:41 v0.5.1
drwxr-xr-x 6 24561 staff    6 2011-08-23 22:41 v0.5.2
drwxr-xr-x 6 24561 staff    6 2011-08-25 00:43 v0.5.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 24561 staff    6 2011-08-23 22:41 v0.5 -> v0.5.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 24561 staff    7 2011-08-23 22:41 v0.4 -> v0.4.11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 24561 staff    6 2011-08-23 22:41 unstable -> v0.5.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 24561 staff    7 2011-08-23 22:41 stable -> v0.4.11
```